# How to change file permissions on Windows via powershell / cmd?

Tags: windows, permissions, powershell, cmd.exe, acl

I want to achieve the permissions aspect equivalent on Windows side via PowerShell or cmd, however I couldn't find a solution in order to correctly do this. If someone could help me to achieve this in the correct way.

```
[sudo] adduser test
[sudo] gcc vuln.c -o vuln -fno-stack-protector -m32 -z execstack
```

the part I am getting issues to make it Windows style

```
[sudo] chown root:test vuln
[sudo] chmod 550 vuln
[sudo] chmod u+s vuln

-r-sr-x--- 1 root test 7392 Dec 22 00:27 vuln
```

Answer (score 11):

The permission system on Windows is called [ACL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-control-lists). To edit the ACL list use

- [cacls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cacls_1) on Windows prior to Vista

  For example to add Read-Only permission to myfile.txt

  ```
  CACLS myfile.txt /E /G "Power Users":R
  ```
- [icacls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls) on Windows Vista and up

  For example to grant the group FileAdmins 'Delete' and 'Write DAC' permissions to C:\demo\example:

  ```
  icacls "C:\demo\example" /grant:r FileAdmins:(D,WDAC)
  ```
- [Get-Acl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-acl?view=powershell-7) and [Set-Acl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-acl?view=powershell-7) in PowerShell

  For example to copy the ACL from C:\Dog.txt to C:\Cat.txt use this

  ```
  Get-Acl -Path "C:\Dog.txt" | Set-Acl -Path "C:\Cat.txt"
  ```

To take ownership you'll need to use [takeown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/takeown): `takeown /f lostfile`. In PowerShell you can use [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity.SetOwner](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setowner?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_AccessControl_ObjectSecurity_SetOwner_System_Security_Principal_IdentityReference_)

For more information

- [What are Windows ACLs?](https://superuser.com/q/246280/241386)
- [How would I use Takeown to take ownership of all folders on one drive?](https://superuser.com/q/813878/241386)
- [PowerShell Change owner of files and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22988384/995714)
- https://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html - https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html
- https://ss64.com/ps/get-acl.html - https://ss64.com/ps/set-acl.html
- https://ss64.com/nt/takeown.html
  [PowerShell Change owner of files and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22988384/995714)